# Is there a home directory location for overriding icons?

Tags: directory-structure, home, icons, xdg

There are a few home directory locations that complement `/usr` locations. Files in these locations override their `/usr` counterparts. For example:

- `~/.local/bin` complements `/usr/bin`
- `~/.local/share/applications` complements `/usr/share/applications`

If I want to override an application, I can create a custom `.desktop` file and store it in `~/.local/share/applications`. This is helpful if I want to tweak how the application is invoked, but overkill if all I want to do is change the icon.

Additionally:

- if the original `.desktop` file is non-trivial I either lose the original functionality or need to keep my local copy in-sync
- I can't modify non-application icons (status icons, etc)

I could [modify or maintain icons in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48`](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/icons.html.en), but I would prefer to maintain them in my home folder, and these would be *fallback* icons not *overriding* icons.

Is there a home folder location that complements `/usr/share/icons`, where I could store application icons and other icons, and they would override existing theme icons?

For example, I'm using the Papirus theme but I want to use my own icon [notepad.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Notepad_icon.svg) for the Text Editor application. This icon is defined in `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop` as `Icon=gedit`. Where should I place `notepad.svg`?

Comment: work in progress https://gitlab.com/snippets/1684859

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The historical equivalent is `~/.icons`, the XDG equivalent is `~/.local/share/icons` (strictly speaking, `icons` subdirectories of the paths in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`). When you specify an icon by name only in a `.desktop` file, that relies on icon themes, so it’s worth reading the [icon theme spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).

Ideally you should use [`xdg-icon-resource`](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-icon-resource.html) to install icons locally.

Comment: Have you tried using `xdg-icon-resource`? Or the appropriate subdirectory of `~/.local/share/icons`?

Comment: That’s what it’s supposed to do, yes. By default it installs in the `hicolor` theme. And yes, “appropriate subdirectory” is `THEME/SIZE` (but you should just use `xdg-icon-resource`).

Comment: I've had a bash at using xdg-icon-resource but I'm not succeeding, so I've updated the question with a concrete example of an app icon replacement, I'll find time tomorrow to expand on my attempts

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in the documentation: "https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html": "By default, apps should look in $HOME/.icons (for backwards compatibility), in $XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons and in /usr/share/pixmaps (in that order)" - the directory "~/.local/share/icons" is nowhere mentioned (and is not part of $XDG_DATA_DIRS)?!

Answer (score 3):

The `xdg-icon-resource` program is apparently stupid about "scalable" SVG icons. It requires a `--size` argument but does not let you specify `scalable` as the size.

I was trying to get the Alacritty icon to work and here is what did it:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
$ mv /tmp/Alacritty.svg ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
```

To explain a bit, the "hicolor" theme is the fallback, default parent of most all Gnome themes. You can see its definitions in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/index.theme`

You can find your current theme with

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
'Yaru'
```

And you can see how it inherits from `hicolor` right at the top:

```
$ head -4 /usr/share/icons/Yaru/index.theme
[Icon Theme]
Name=Yaru
Comment=A desktop adaptation of the Ubuntu mobile icons.
Inherits=Humanity,hicolor
```

If you are trying to override the icon for a specific theme then you need to put the icon into the directory for that theme because putting it into `hicolor` would not override it for `Yaru`, for example.