# Assign an icon to a custom mimetype

Tags: gnome, configuration, icons, mime-types, xdg

I tried to create a custom mimetype (text/graphml+xml) by creating the file ~/.local/share/mime/packages/graphml+xml-mime.xml with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
   <mime-type type="text/x-graphml+xml">
   <comment>GraphML file</comment>
   <acronym>GraphML</acronym>
   <expanded-acronym>Graph Modelling Language</expanded-acronym>
   <sub-class-of type="text/xml"/>
   <glob pattern="*.graphml"/>
  </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

And installed an appropriate icon with:

```
xdg-icon-resource-resourse install --context mimetype --novendor --size ${size} --mode user text-x-graphml+xml.png
```

Then updated the database with

```
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

But the icon for a my.graphml file is not displayed in nautilus (it's a debian minimal gnome system).

The icons in ~/.local/share/icon/hicolor/${size}x${size}/mimetype/text-x-graphml+xml.png does exist.

gio info my.graphml says:

```
...
standard::icon: text-x-graphml+xml, text-x-generic, text-x-graphml+xml-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic
standard::content-type: text/x-graphml+xml
standard::fast-content-type: text/x-graphml+xml
...
```

I can double click it and the file is opened with yed (as I want - did create the ~/.local/share/applicatons/yed.desktop file)

But no icon! :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The fix

Use this XML file instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
   <mime-type type="application/x-graphml+xml">
   <comment>GraphML file</comment>
   <acronym>GraphML</acronym>
   <expanded-acronym>Graph Modelling Language</expanded-acronym>
   <glob pattern="*.graphml"/>
   <icon name="x-graphml+xml"/>
  </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

and make sure you run `xdg-icon-resource`
with

```
--context mimetypes
```

not

```
--context mimetype
```

otherwise they'll go in the wrong folder.

For example, if the icon is 48x48, the installation commands will look like this:

```
xdg-mime install --mode user graphml+xml-mime.xml
xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 48 text-x-graphml+xml.png x-graphml+xml
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
update-icon-caches ~/.local/share/icons
```

## Attempt at an explanation

This is a strange one.
It appears the difficulty is that when the mimetype is

```
text/x-graphml+xml
```

instead of

```
application/x-graphml+xml
```

it defaults to the generic text icon.
This seems to depend on the file manager and desktop, though.

Is this a bug? You decide!

Comment: 1.st of all, thanks.

Now... It doesn't make much sense to me... what I'd like to register is a "type of file" based on text.

Should I install both .xml (the one with

<mime-type type="text/x-graphml+xml">

and the one with
<mime-type type="application/x-graphml+xml">

)? Or will they conflict with one another?

Comment: Ideally only one mimetype will be installed, although I don't think they will conflict because whichever is the most recently installed will take priority.